# WordPress website not working with domain name but IP address

Tags: wordpress, apache2, vps, broken-links

http://sidparmar.ca/portfolio/ This is my portfolio website and an only home page is working with the domain name. Every link is broken unless replaced by IP of my VPS which is 64.20.53.42.

So usually it should work like sidparmar.ca/portfolio/contact/ (give me an error "The requested URL /portfolio/resume/ was not found on this server.")
but currently, it is only working if I type 64.20.53.42/portfolio/contact/ as URL.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions/advice or pointer that I should look into. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the answer by myself! Yeah!

I just added "ServerAlias www.domainname.ca" to my apache2 conf file (000-default.conf) which you can probably find at /etc/apache2/sites-available directory in your VPS.

Not sure why this worked or what exactly caused the problem but I am sure that it happened because of Yoast SEO plugin.

Answer (score -1):

Has your site been like this since you installed Wordpress?  If so, then where did you install wordpress (i.e. what directory)?  It looks like you did not install it in the web root directory of your web server.  Also, when you installed Wordpress, are you sure you specified the correct URL of your website?

My suggestion based on the limited information you provided and the minor amount of custom content of your website is to simply delete your database and files, create a new database, and re-installation Wordpress following exactly the correct instructions.  Your VPS host may have an outlined process for you.

Alternatively, if this is a new issue, do you think you caused it?  If so, what did you do?  If not, you should probably contact your VPS host to see if you or they need to make an update in your DNS settings.

Comment: My site was working perfectly until this morning. I installed Yoast SEO plugin and made some changes for SEO and I found out that it messed up everything.

Comment: My site was working perfectly until this morning. I installed Yoast SEO plugin and made some changes for SEO and I found out that it messed up everything. My website is installed at /var/www/html/portfolio

I found out that it is a problem with permalinks. If I change my permalinks to plain, everything works and not otherwise.
My .htaccess file is:
# BEGIN
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /portfolio/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /portfolio/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END

Comment: If you think this is an issue with Yoast, did you try deactivating it and uninstalling it?  Fully?  (i.e. including removing any Yoast changes to .htaccess or wp-config.php?)  If you are sure Yoast broke your site, I would try searching the Yoast support forum here: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wordpress-seo.  Also, Yoast support forum usually provides good support because they don't want negative reviews and want to ensure that their product is working as it should.

Comment: I am sure it happened after I made lots of changes using Yoast. So currently I deactivated all the plugins. It also broke my other WordPress website (sidparmar.ca/wordpress). same prob, home page works nothing else if I go with postname permalinks. I will try to look for yoast support but I am not sure if they could help me

Comment: If the issue is with how your site handles permalinks, (nice work debugging), you might want to check out this too: https://fancythemes.com/fix-broken-permalinks-wordpress/

Comment: Thank you, I already went through that article. I am suspecting that the problem is with Apache server (not 100% sure). I am using VPS with Ubuntu. I changed the rights of the .htacess file as suggested to 644 as suggested but still nothing.